# Custom control's content can't bind to parent of the control

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemtemplate

I have following XAML (simplified, no ending tags):

```
<Window Name="myWindow" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}" >
    <DockPanel>
        <tb:ToolBar Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <tb:ToolBar.Items>
                <tb:ToolBarControl Priority="-3">
                    <tb:ToolBarControl.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock>Maps:</TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Generator.Maps, ElementName=myWindow}">
```

But the `ComboBox`'s binding will fail with

> Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=myWindow'

Some facts about the custom controls:

- `tb:ToolBar` is `UserControl` which contains  actual `ToolBar` with `ItemsSource` bound to the `Items` property of the `tb:ToolBar` (of type inheriting `IList`).
- The `ToolBar`'s `ToolBarItem` `DataTemplate` is chosen from several `DataTemplate`s (according to the type of the item).
- The DataTemplate belonging to the `tb:ToolBarControl` is very simple - it just contains `ContentPresenter` bound to property `Content` of the `tb:ToolBarControl`.
- `tb:ToolBarControl` is not for technical reasons `UserControl`, it is just `DependencyObject` with property `Content` of type `object`.

Why can't the `ComboBox` reference the `Window`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the failure is from the ComboBox? <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Generator.Maps, ElementName=window}"> says window not myWindow but in the error msg it says 'ElementName=myWindow'

Comment: @Xim It is because I have changed names from original. And the binding error specifies its origin. The original full error is "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=view2D'. BindingExpression:Path=Generator.Maps; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')". And yes, "view2D" is name of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem here:

[Bindings on child dependency object of usercontrol not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956041/wpf-bindings-on-child-dependency-object-of-usercontrol-not-working)

DependencyObject doesn't have a DataContext and I think that's why the binding doesn't work. Instead of inheriting from 'DependencyObject' try inheriting from FrameworkElement.

Comment: I see, but I can't just change the base type to UIElement, because `ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='ToolBarControl'`. Looks like I will have to rewrite the data templates to control templates :(

Comment: I improved my code according to your advice, but it still won't work. I posted a second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546116/binding-from-items-of-an-itemscontrol-with-custom-collection