# Binding from items of an UserControl with custom collection property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

This question is a "sequel" to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144009/custom-controls-content-cant-bind-to-parent-of-the-control) (I have applied the answer, but it still won't work).

I'm trying to create an extended ToolBar control for a modular application, which can load its items from multiple data sources (but that is not the issue I'm trying to solve right now, now I want it to work when used as regular ToolBar found in WPF).

In short: **I want the ToolBar's items to be able to bind to the tb:ToolBar's parents.**

I have following XAML code:

```
<Window Name="myWindow" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}" >
    <DockPanel>
        <tb:ToolBar Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}>
            <tb:ToolBar.Items>
                <tb:ToolBarControl Priority="-3">
                    <tb:ToolBarControl.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock>Maps:</TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=myWindow}">
```

Some info about the types:

- `tb:ToolBar` is an `UserControl` with dependency property `Items` of type `FreezableCollection<ToolBarControl>`.
- `tb:ToolBarControl` is an `UserControl` with template pretty much identical to [ContentControl's template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334411%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

**The problem is that the binding in the `ComboBox` fails** (with the usual "Cannot find source for binding with reference"), because its DataContext is null.

**Why?**

EDIT: The core of the question is "Why is the DataContext not inherited?", without it, the bindings can't work.

EDIT2:

Here is XAML for the `tb:ToolBar`:

```
<UserControl ... Name="toolBarControl">
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=toolBarControl}" Name="toolBar" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26">
```

EDIT 3:

I posted an example of what works and what doesn't: http://pastebin.com/Tyt1Xtvg

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: tb:ToolBar and tb:ToolBarControl, are they custom control or usercontrol?

Comment: @Xin Both are UserControl (which I have also specified in the post).

Comment: Yeah... I saw that, the reason that I asked is I wonder how you can make a usercontrol templated?

Comment: @Xin I created it originally as a simple class and only converted it to UserControl later (see the first thread I linked to in the post). The template is defined in Themes/generic.xaml (and I can pretty much turn it into CustomControl just by changing its ancestor, but I don't have any reason right now). The control itself works - it renders okay (the whole tb:ToolBar renders okay), just the bindings fail.

Comment: Also I wonder why you need to do this <Window Name="myWindow" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}" > and this 
    <DockPanel> 
        <tb:ToolBar Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}> The data context should automatically flow down, doing this might break the context inheritence.

Comment: Did you at least try what I updated?

Comment: I just updated my answer for your Edit 3

Comment: I have updated my answer, again, hope this time it works. :)

Comment: @Xin I will look at it, but I was a bit busy for last two days, so I didn't get to experiment on the visual tree stuff. Don't worry, I won't let the bounty expire :)

Comment: No problem, it's not the bounty I'm worried about, I also want to get to the bottom of it, it's indeed a good question, ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't like the idea of setting `DataContext` in controls. I think doing this will somehow break the data context inheritance. Please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153787/whats-wrong-with-datacontext-this-in-wpf-user-controls). I think Simon explained it pretty well.

At least, try removing

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}"
```

from

```
<tb:ToolBar Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}>
```

and see how it goes.

**UPDATE**

Actually, keep all your existing code (ignore my previous suggestion for a moment), just change

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=myWindow}">
```

to

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty}">
```

and see if it works.

I think because of the way you structure your controls, the `ComboBox` is at the same level/scope as the `tb:ToolBarControl` and the `tb:ToolBar`. That means they all share the same `DataContext`, so you don't really need any `ElementName` binding or `RelativeSource` binding to try to find its parent/ancestor.

If you remove `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}` from the `tb:ToolBar`, you can even get rid of the prefix `DataContext` in the binding. And this is really all you need.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty}">
```

**UPDATE 2** to answer your **Edit 3**

This is because your `Items` collection in your `tb:ToolBar` usercontrol is just a property. It's not in the logical and visual tree, and I believe `ElementName` binding uses logical tree.

That's why it is not working.

**Add to logical tree**

I think to add the `Items` into the logical tree you need to do two things.

First you need to override the `LogicalChildren` in your `tb:ToolBar` usercontrol.

```
    protected override System.Collections.IEnumerator LogicalChildren
    {
        get
        {
            if (Items.Count == 0)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then whenever you added a new `tb:ToolBarControl` you need to call

```
AddLogicalChild(item);
```

Give it a shot.

**This WORKS...**

After playing around with it a little bit, I think what I showed you above isn't enough. You will also need to add these `ToolBarControls` to your main window's name scope to enable `ElementName` binding. I assume this is how you defined your `Items` dependency property.

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
                                typeof(ToolBarControlCollection),
                                typeof(ToolBar),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ToolBarControlCollection(), Callback));
```

In the callback, it is where you add it to the name scope.

```
private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var toolbar = (ToolBar)d;
    var items = toolbar.Items;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        // the panel that contains your ToolBar usercontrol, in the code that you provided it is a DockPanel
        var panel = (Panel)toolbar.Parent;
        // your main window
        var window = panel.Parent;
        // add this ToolBarControl to the main window's name scope
        NameScope.SetNameScope(item, NameScope.GetNameScope(window));

        // ** not needed if you only want ElementName binding **
        // this enables bubbling (navigating up) in the visual tree
        //toolbar.AddLogicalChild(item);
    }
}
```

Also if you want property inheritance, you will need

```
// ** not needed if you only want ElementName binding **
// this enables tunneling (navigating down) in the visual tree, e.g. property inheritance
//protected override System.Collections.IEnumerator LogicalChildren
//{
//    get
//    {
//        if (Items.Count == 0)
//        {
//            yield break;
//        }

//        foreach (var item in Items)
//        {
//            yield return item;
//        }
//    }
//}
```

I have tested the code and it works fine.

Comment: I removed the DataContext from the tb:ToolBar declaration and it didn't change anything (for better or worse), I guess it was just remnant of my earlier attempts to fix the problem.

Comment: I've just updated the answer, please do a test and let me know.

Comment: @Xim Your UPDATE actually seems to work - what a simple fix! As for Update 2, do you know how could I make it a part of the tree (just like the original ToolBar does)?

Comment: You probably need to change it to a custom control. You want something like a ListBox with ListBoxItems, in your case ToolBar and ToolBarControls.

Comment: @Xim I which sense would making it a CustomControl help me? AFAIK UserControl is mostly a Control with associated XAML file (and it is a Custom) and a Content property (inherited from ContentControl).

Comment: Your ToolBar control is just a usercontrol right? If it inherits from usercontrol, how can you also make it inherited from ContentControl? You just can't mix them up like that.

Comment: @Xim UserControl inherits from ContentControl, most people (me included) rarely use the Content property though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5326/discussion-between-xin-and-matj-zabsky)

Answer (score 2):

I took the pieces of Xaml that you posted and tried to reproduce your problem.

The `DataContext` seems to be inheriting just fine from what I can tell. However, `ElementName` Bindings fail and I think this has to do with the fact that even though you add the `ComboBox` in the `Window`, it ends up in a different scope. *(It is first added to the `Items` property of the custom `ToolBar` and is then populated to the framework `ToolBar` with a Binding)*

A `RelativeSource` Binding instead of an `ElementName` Binding seems to be working fine.

But if you really want to use the name of the control in the Binding, then you could check out [Dr.WPF's excellent `ObjectReference` implementation](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/02/supplying-an-object-reference-in-the-constructorparameters-collection-of-an-objectdataprovider/)

It would look something like this

```
<Window ...
        tb:ObjectReference.Declaration="{tb:ObjectReference myWindow}">
<!--...-->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeProperty,
                                Source={tb:ObjectReference myWindow}}"
```

I uploaded a small sample project where both `RelativeSource` and `ObjectReference` are succesfully used here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tx5vdqlm8mywgzw/ToolBarTest.zip?dl=0

The custom `ToolBar` part as I approximated it looks like this in the `Window`.
`ElementName` Binding fails but `RelativeSource` and `ObjectReference` Bindings work

```
<Window ...
    Name="myWindow"
    tb:ObjectReference.Declaration="{tb:ObjectReference myWindow}">
<!--...-->
<tb:ToolBar x:Name="toolbar"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}">
    <tb:ToolBar.Items>
        <tb:ContentControlCollection>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock>Maps:</TextBlock>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StringList,
                                                        ElementName=myWindow}"
                                    SelectedIndex="0"/>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StringList,
                                                        Source={tb:ObjectReference myWindow}}"
                                    SelectedIndex="0"/>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StringList,
                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                    SelectedIndex="0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentControl.Content>
            </ContentControl>
        </tb:ContentControlCollection>
    </tb:ToolBar.Items>
</tb:ToolBar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and example). However, I would like to see why WPF's ToolBar works and my tb:ToolBar doesn't, so I can fix it. Full sample here: http://pastebin.com/Tyt1Xtvg Of course, if nobody can answer that, I will accept your answer, because it appears to solve my immediate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Often if there is no `DataContext` then `ElementName` will not work either. One thing which you can try if the situation allows it is using [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx).

For that you need to move the bound control into the resources of the referenced control, change the binding and use `StaticResource` in the place where it was, e.g.

```
<Window Name="myWindow" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ComboBox x:Key="cb"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty,
                                        Source={x:Reference myWindow}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <tb:ToolBar Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}>
            <tb:ToolBar.Items>
                <tb:ToolBarControl Priority="-3">
                    <tb:ToolBarControl.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock>Maps:</TextBlock>
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="cb"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer is probably to add everything to the logical tree as mentioned in previous answers, but the following code has proved to be convenient for me.  I can't post all the code I have, but...

Write your own Binding MarkupExtension that gets you back to the root element of your XAML file.  *This code was not compiled as I hacked up my real code to post this.*

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class RootBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public RootElementBinding(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IRootObjectProvider rootObjectProvider =
            (IRootObjectProvider)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider));

        Binding binding = new Binding(this.Path);
        binding.Source = rootObjectProvider.RootObject;

        // Return raw binding if we are in a non-DP object, like a Style
        if (service.TargetObject is DependencyObject == false)
            return binding;

        // Otherwise, return what a normal binding would
        object providedValue = binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

        return providedValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={myBindings:RootBinding DataContext.SomeProperty} />
```